# Why is the value of the input way higher than the output resulting in a second change output?

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, bitcoin-core-development, testnet

Background: I'm experimenting on the LTC testnet client.

My client has a balance of 0.4 LTC and I sent 0.1 LTC to another wallet address.

https://chain.so/tx/LTCTEST/cc7d6e5e488593fded214e3073195fbaca3807a27d18a7f2550b6fc4909c48f6

Why is the value of the input 0.19 instead of 0.1? Why is this type of transaction created?

Why can't a transaction just be created with 0.1 input and 0.1 output without any change returned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like mw1eydzkEHohfjcL9xBJNaJEQbFF93Y25F

Got a donation of 0.09

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the value of the input 0.19 instead of 0.1? Why is this type of transaction created?

Bitcoin works on a system of transaction outputs. Transaction outputs are spent as inputs to another transaction. When they are spent, they must be spent in full. The input of your transaction is spending an output with value 0.19, so all 0.19 Bitcoin must be spent in full in this input. The remainder must then be sent to a change output.

> Why can't a transaction just be created with 0.1 input and 0.1 output without any change returned?

Inputs don't actually have a value attached to them; what block explorers show you as the input value is really the value of the output being spent.